# setting a css variable via javascript

Tags: javascript, css-variables

I am trying to get the height and width of the browser window and display it on the body as well as changing the height to match.

Here's my current code:

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
  width = this.innerWidth;
  height = this.innerHeight;
  document.body.innerHTML = width + 'x' + height; // For demo purposes
}
```

The above code displays the width and height on the body ok, now time to add it to a css variable:

```
var header = document.querySelector('.header')

window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
  width = this.innerWidth;
  height = this.innerHeight;
  header.style.setProperty('--height', height);
  header.style.setProperty('--width', width);
  document.body.innerHTML = width + 'x' + height; // For demo purposes
}
```

I know the code is not correct but I can't find any sample to compare with, here's a fiddle just in case the code is not enough.

https://jsfiddle.net/rbtwsxd8/6/

Comment: Did you look in console...? `header` is `null`. You've put your code in the `<head>` without waiting for the document to load, so the selectors won't find their elements. You're also re-writing the `<body>` on resize, thus removing your `header` element entirely.

Comment: apologies I'm new to javascript. Don't understand why that is null, if I use document.getElementById("header") and change the class to id on the div and replace the line header.style.setProperty('--height', height); with document.getElementById("header").style.setProperty('--height', height); that works I think although my size still doesnt change

Comment: In JSFiddle, you've set the code to embed *"No wrap in <head>"*, meaning it will get embedded in the head of your page in `<script>` tags. This portion of the code *loads before the rest of the page*, therefore when your line of code hits to find `header`, it hasn't loaded yet and therefore is not found. Options are to wrap it in an `onLoad` listener (so it runs when the page is finished loading), or to throw it at the end of your `<body>` (so it only gets hit *after* the `<body>` has loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of different issues here:

- (at least in the fiddle) you were trying to `document.queryselect` the header element before it existed
- your debug code overwrote the header element by setting `document.body`
- You omitted the units when setting the height and width  (This used to work in "quirks mode" but will not work in modern doctypes.)
- You added extra double hyphens when trying to set the height and width

Here's a working version which corrects these problems:

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
  var header = document.querySelector('.header');

  // your original code used 'this.innerWidth' etc, which does work
  // (because the function is being run on the window object) but can
  // be confusing; may be better to refer to the window object 
  // explicitly:
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  header.style.width = width + "px"; // need 'px' units
  header.style.height = height + "px";
  // the above is equivalent shorthand for
  // header.style.setProperty('height', window.innerHeight + 'px');
  // header.style.setProperty('width', window.innerWidth + 'px');

  // setting this inside the header, so we don't remove it in the process:
  header.innerHTML = width + "x" + height;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pm7rgx4q/1/

Comment: But where is a CSS variable here?

Comment: under "style".   `foo.style` is the CSS object for DOM element `foo`.

Comment: @DjordjeVujicic `header.style.height` is the CSS height variable for the `header` element.  It's shorthand equivalent for `style.setProperty`; I've clarified that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I felt both answers worked but as you mentioned in one of your comments, the explanations with your code has helped a great deal and makes it much easier to learn and see where I went wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
    var header = document.querySelector('.header')
    width = this.innerWidth;
    height = this.innerHeight;
    header.innerHTML = width + 'x' + height; // For demo purposes
    header.style.setProperty('height', height + 'px')
    header.style.setProperty('width', width + 'px');
   //header.style.height = height + 'px';
   //header.style.width =width + 'px';
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbtwsxd8/12/)

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter in this case, but this is the sort of answer I often *do* downvote:  it's just a code dump, with no explanation of what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: The questioner just ask for code to compare. Let him learn by asking.

Comment: I don't agree that that's very helpful, @FazalRasel, but that's why there's an upvote/downvote system in the first place: we all get to vote on what constitutes a good answer.